# Attempt to fetch logical page in database 5 failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dbcc

When I run a select query, I get the error:

> Msg 605, Level 21, State 3, Line 1
>   Attempt to fetch logical page (1:XXXXXXX) in database 5 failed. It belongs to allocation unit XXXXXXXXXXX not to XXXXXXXXXXXXX.

I have tried running query `DBCC CheckDB`. C: Drive almost full before query completed so query was not completed and did not get error.

I have no database backup. How can I fix this error.

Comment: Add more disk space first.